# How can I echo out a timestamp pulled out from an SQL database table to be in the user's timezone?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have records that user's create by submitting a form on my website. When they create a record, a timestamp is also created by default to explain when the record was created. From what I'm aware they are all in UTC/GMT Time which is 4 hours off my EST timezone.  When I loop through the records to echo them into a table, I'd like for the timestamp's to show the time of the user logged in. Is there easy way of going about this by changing the variable of the timestamp?

Comment: you tried to set Default Timezone?

Comment: `SET time_zone = 'US/Eastern'`, its done differently depending on if you are using `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-4 hours',strtotime(TIME_FROM_DB)));
```

For more about date() & strtotime() see http://php.net/manual/de/

In MYSQL:

```
 SELECT DATE_ADD(time_field, INTERVAL 31 DAY);
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate

hope helps

Answer (score 0):

Using `date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');` in PHP will convert the time-zone of your code to that timezone.

When you query the database with `NOW()` in the SQL-query (or use `$currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());` in PHP, and insert `$currentTime`), it'll insert the time of the time-zone defined above.